# Posting to mvc controller action always return error

Tags: javascript, .net, model-view-controller

I am new to mvc and I am tring to use ajax to get and post data. Get is working fine  but when I use post using the same ajax code while change it to post give me always error 400. I tried with many type of data sent and the action in the controller is empty to eleminate that the error occour there although i new 400 error is a bad request but I couldn't figure it out.
The code is as follow

```
      async function SaveTheDay(url, data) {
       if (data != null) {
            $.ajax({
             url: url,
            type: 'POST',
           dataType: "json",
           data: data,
            success: function (response) {
               if (response) {
                console.log("Ok");
               } else {
                console.log("not valid ");
              }
           },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
            console.log("error "+status+"    "+error);
            }
          })//not null
       }
     }//SaveTheDay
```

the controller action is :

```
            [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
             public async Task<IActionResult> SaveDay(InfoDay day)
              {
                return View("DayTrial");
              }
```

and I call the function when the save button cliked as:
//define the object

```
      var infoDay =
       {
          userId :userId,
           date: TheDate.value ,
          items :items ,
          itemsAmount : itemsAmount, 
             itemsMealTime  :itemsMealTime,
         dailyConsumedkCal: dailyConsumedkCal, 
           dayTotal  :"",
         bloodData  :"",
        bloodSugarData :"", 
        sleepData  :"",
         indexData  :"",
         dayCost  :0
     }

SaveTheDay("/Days/SaveDay", infoDay);
```

here is the InfoDay class

```
   public class InfoDay
     {
        public int userId { get; 
      set; }  
    public string date { get; set; 
    }  
    public string? items { get; 
    set; }  
    public string? itemsAmount { 
      get; set; }  
    public string? itemsMealTime { 
            get; set; }
    public int? dailyConsumedkCal 
        { get; set; }  
     public string? dayTotal { 
     get; set; }  
    public string? bloodData { 
     get; set; }  
    public string? bloodSugarData 
    { get; set; }  
    public string? sleepData { 
       get; set; }  
    public string? indexData { 
     get; set; }  
    public int? dayCost { get; 
     set; } = 0;
   }
```

Comment: First, do you know what a http status code of what 400 means? it means bad request. Why is it a bad request? because its a post request to a get endpoint. this is not a JS issue. its your MVC, change the route type to accept post not get.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Actually the action has the : [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

        public async Task<IActionResult> SaveDay(InfoDay day)
        {

Comment: Can you share the InfoDay class? Maybe JS object data doesn't match the C# class structure.

Comment: It works now when I removed the :            
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] from the action on the controller. It solved my problem for now but I dont think that I should remove it. @Miriam:I tried with empty action but it didn't work either

Comment: @Miriam: I add the InfoDay class.

Answer (score 0):

The ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute prevents 'Cross-site request forgery' attacks in your MVC application.
See [https://learn.microsoft.com/..../security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
Do not remove it.

To avoid the 400 error, you must pass the token with your POST request.

```js
    async function SaveTheDay(url, data) {
       if (data != null) {
            $.ajax({
             url: url,
            type: 'POST',
           dataType: "json",
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('RequestVerificationToken',
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
            success: function (response) {
               if (response) {
                console.log("Ok");
               } else {
                console.log("not valid ");
              }
           },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
            console.log("error "+status+"    "+error);
            }
          })//not null
       }
     }//SaveTheDay
```

Of course the hidden field with the token has to be present in the view.
The HTML Helper Html.AntiForgeryToken includes the token.

```html
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

If you use a form tag helper, the token is also included.
See [https://learn.microsoft.com...?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-form-tag-helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-form-tag-helper)